# Replace data starts with '...' with np.NaN

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with string data starts with '...'. How to replace the string value in the DataFrame with np.NaN?

I used the following : `df.replace('...', np.NaN, inplace=True)`
.It of course doesn't replace all data start with '...'.

I intend to use regExp as `df.replace('^\.',np.NaN, inplace=True)`
but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me to pass a regular expression into `df.replace`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.replace`, specifying `regex=True`:

```
In [447]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['foo', '...', 'bar', '...test', '...']})

In [448]: df.replace(r'^\.\.\..*', np.nan, regex=True)
Out[448]: 
  Col1
0  foo
1  NaN
2  bar
3  NaN
4  NaN
```

Comment: Wouldn't the desired output also be `NaN` for `...test`?

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed it :)